# How to implement apply pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

What is apply invocation pattern in Javascript in reference to function invocation patterns and how can I use it?
What are the benefits of using this invocation pattern.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The use of `apply` is related to the function context (the `this` keyword) and argument passing.

First, I think you should know in which cases the `this` keyword is **implicitly** set:

1- When a function is called as a method (the function is invoked as member of an object):

```
obj.method(); // 'this' inside method will refer to obj
```

2- A normal function call:

```
myFunction(); // 'this' inside the function will refer to the Global object
// or 
(function () {})();
```

3- When the `new` operator is used:

```
var obj = new MyObj(); // this will refer to a newly created object.
```

Here is when `apply` and `call` come, those methods let you set **explicitly** the context when you invoke a function, eg.:

```
function test(a) {
  alert(this + a);
}

test.call('Hello', ' world!');
```

In the above code, when the `test` function is called setting the `this` keyword to a String (`'Hello'`), and passing the `a` argument (`' world.'`).

Both, `call` and `apply` change the context of the executing function (the `this` keyword) inside the called function, but the **difference** between them is that with `apply`, you can send an Array or an Array-like object as the arguments of the function to be executed, which is extremely useful, for example:

```
function sum() {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i];
  }
  return result;
}

var args = [1,2,3];
sum.apply(null, args); // will return 6
```

That can avoid some very hacky, **bad** (and common) `eval` calls like:

```
eval('sum(' + args.join() +')');
```

Another example, the `Math.max` and `Math.min` methods, those methods can receive an arbitrary number of arguments like:

```
var max = Math.max(2,4,6,8); // 8
```

But what if you have an Array of numbers?

```
var numbers = [2,4,6,8];
numbers.push(10);
var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); // 10
```

Also note that when `null` or `undefined` is used as the `this` argument with `call` or `apply`, the `this` object will refer to the Global object (similar to the case #2, normal function invocation).

For the `Math.max` example, the context is not really relevant, since they are just like *"static"* methods, the `this` keyword is not used internally...

Comment: Ah I think I get it now. The whole point that I missed was "the value of this is provided as the first parameters". Now it makes sense why we would like to differentiate apply method as a separate kind of invocation.
So what is the diff. between call and apply keywords then?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use call/apply for inheritance.

```
function Client (id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = "Client" + id;
}

Client.prototype = {
    constructor: Client

  , toString: function () {
      return this.name;
    }
};

function WebClient (id) {
  Client.call (this, id);
}

WebClient.prototype = new Client ();

WebClient.prototype.constructor = WebClient;

WebClient.prototype.ping = function () {
  // do stuff
};
```

Notice `Client.call (this, id);` This executes `Client` using the `this` instance that a `new WebClient` would create. Thus when

```
  this.id = id;
  this.name = "Client" + id;
```

are executed inside `Client` the `WebClient` instance is getting assigned those properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any design patterns named The Apply Pattern so I don't really think this is at all related to design patterns. However, there is an apply method of function objects in javascript (along with the corresponding call method) so I'll be explaining those.

The apply and call methods basically allow an object to "steal" a method from another object. You see, in javascript, methods are bound very-very late: at invocation time. Only when a method is called is the value of `'this'` resolved. In a normal method call:

```
some_object.do_something();
```

the `'this'` keyword in do_something refers to some_object. Apply and call lets you re-assign `'this'`. For example:

```
some_object.do_something.apply(another_object);
```

the `'this'` keyword in do_something now refers to another_object. So you're calling the do_something method belonging to some_object on another_object.

Now, this is interesting and all but why would anyone want to do this? Here's a concrete example of why this is useful:

```
// say you want to get some DIVs in the document, you can get all of them with:
var some_divs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');

// say you want the third to fifth DIV in the document, some_divs looks like an
// array so you might think you can slice it, but it's not. It's a collection
// of elements that fakes being an array and doesn't implement the slice method.

// No worries, we can steal the slice method from an array 
// and apply it to some_divs:
var wanted_divs = [].slice.apply(some_divs,[2,5]);

// Alternatively:
var wanted_divs = [].slice.call(some_divs,2,5);
```

There is another use case for apply which is a result of the difference between how apply and call works. If you have all your arguments in an array and the function expects individual arguments you can use apply to pass the array and have the function see the content of the array as individual arguments:

```
function some_function (first,second) {
    alert(first+second);
}
var argument_array = ['hello','world'];
some_function.apply(null, argument_array);
```